# Supply correct pixel format & parameters from gphoto2 feeding into ffmpeg using v4l2loopback

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l, gphoto2

I have Nikon D3300 camera and want to feed video output into my computer as part of live streaming with OBS.

I successfully installed [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) as well as `gphoto2` on my Ubuntu 18.04. I already had `ffmpeg` installed. (Their all version information can be found at the bottom)

Then I execute the command `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2`. I tested to see video output via `guvcview` and OBS. It shows video output properly but with one issue. It looks greenish like this (captured from OBS).

[image]

I also asked in v4l2loopback on [github](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/218) and developer pin-points that the problem is with the parameters feeding the program i.e. `gphoto2` (or need some adjustment of parameters in `ffmpeg` too or not I'm not sure).

So do you know whether I use the right parameters? or else what's the right ones to solve this greenish video output.

Comment: The developer suggests primarily that: "..most likely these frames do not have any colourspace information, so you must pass the correct value to ffmpeg...". Looks like the relevant options are here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace but I am out of my depth there :(

Comment: @haxpor Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I'll come back here for more logs of command. Because I put the camera back, and it needs some time to setup.